# Window.location.href giving a flick in IE8

Tags: javascript

I am opening a excel file with javascript using `window.location.href('URL');`

It is working fine in Firefox, Safari, but in IE8 it is showing a blank screen and then a file dialog. What's the problem in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Open it in an iFrame instead.

```
<iframe name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

and your **JS** will be:

```
hiddenframe.src = "myexcelfile.xlsx";
```

Comment: m pasing the URL from .cs file to Javascript function.then i directy want to open the excel file.No other click required

Comment: Edited my answer to add JS sample. I hope this helps.